# Union with no duplicate only for first column

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I am using the UNION syntax to retrieve a product code and description from several databases.

I want to retrieve only a unique product code, even if this product code has several descriptions. I want to retreive only the first result.

To do that, I am using this script:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT tab1.code, tab1.description FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT tab2.code, tab2.description FROM tab2
UNION
SELECT tab3.code, tab3.description FROM tab3)
```

Unfortunately, this script will retrieve several product codes if the specific product has more than one description.

How can this be modified to retrieve only the first occurrence with a description?

Comment: When you say `first` do you mean `first alphabetically`, or possibly `the first description written to the database`?  If the latter, is there another field we can use to identify which record was `first`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query might be more efficient with a `full outer join`, if there are *no* duplicates within a table and `description` does not take on `NULL` values:

```
SELECT coalesce(tab1.code, tab2.code, tab3.code) as code,
       coalesce(tab1.description, tab2.description, tab3.description) as description
FROM tab1 full outer join
     tab2
     on tab2.code = tab1.code full outer join
     tab3
     on tab3.code = coalesce(tab1.code, tab2.code);
```

This saves the duplicate elimination step (or aggregation) and allows better use of indexes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want ANY one description, you can go with max or min like this:

```
select code, max(description) from (your set of unions)
group by code
```

In this case, you can change UNION to UNION ALL to skip on sorting.

If you really want the first one, you would need to indicate it:

```
select code, description from (
select code, description, ord, min(ord) over (partition by code) min_ord from ( 
select code, description, 1 as ord from table1
union all
select code, description, 2 as ord from table2
union all
select code, description, 3 as ord from table3
)
) where ord = min_ord
```

Comment: +1 : Though, just to be picky, the *first* in a list is equivalent to `MIN()` rather than `MAX()` ;)  *[Owing to the default ordering being Ascending.]*

Comment: @MatBailie : I guess you are wrong - neither MIN nor MAX picks first element in this case (assuming description is a string).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this solution works but maybe it is not elegant.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT tab1.code, tab1.description FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT tab2.code, tab2.description FROM tab2 WHERE tab2.code not in 
(SELECT tab1.code FROM tab1)
UNION
SELECT tab3.code, tab3.description FROM tab3 WHERE tab3.code not in 
(SELECT tab1.code FROM tab1 
UNION
SELECT tab2.code FROM tab2)
)
```

Comment: What if one code has more than one description in the same table?

Comment: @MatBailie: Then we don't know how to select the first of them.

Comment: @David-IT: Like it. Better to replace UNION with UNION ALL

Comment: @vav - Except that *your* answer *does* have a mechanism for picking the *alphabetical* first of each.

Comment: @MatBailie: I still think that this solution is about the same to deal with multiply rows. It is better if you don't want analitical function (plan to use mysql for example), it is bad if you will have tab3, tab4,... And I believe by "not elegant" David-IT mean exactly that.